# How to call for element ID as ("identification" + i)

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have the code written as below. I am suspecting that it is the way I am calling the element ID that is the causing an error.

I need to be able to call for the element ID using the form ("eventstarttime" + i) in the for loop as I will have a large number of inputs that will increase in count. For eg. eventstarttime1, eventstarttime2, eventstarttime3 and so on...

Really need some advice on this. Thanks.

---

This below is my html code

```
<input id="eventstarttime1" type="time" step="1" required>
<input id="eventendtime1" type="time" step="1" required>
<input id="eventstarttime2" type="time" step="1" required>
<input id="eventendtime2" type="time" step="1" required>
```

This below is my javascript code

```
for (i = 1; i < 10 + 1; i++) {
                var eventstarttime = document.getElementById("eventsstarttime" + i).value;
                var eventendtime = document.getElementById("eventendtime" + i).value;
```

Comment: Why have you put `i < numberOfEvents + 1` in the loop?

Comment: Sorry had made the changes, accidentally typed wrongly

Comment: I would recommend using classes.

Comment: This is totally improper... omitting the fact that this loop will be called on page load and will return just empty values, you will overwrite the `eventstarttime` and `eventendtime` variables value with each cycle of the for loop. Consider changing the strategy.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to get the elements by the type: $("input[type=time]"). in this way you get an array of elements then you can loop throw it and gets the value of it.

```
$.each($("input[type=time]"),function(){
var eventstarttime= this.val();
});
```